# Display Correlation table in R shiny

Tags: r

I tried to display correlation table (Val1 and Val2) with the below code. But not sure what wrong I am doing here. Request anyone help me in solving this? Below is the reprex. I am trying to display correlation table under Chart A

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

```{r}
df <- structure(list(Cat = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Val1 = c(1, 4, 6), Val2 = c(4, 7, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
dataTableOutput("t10")
output$t10 <- DT::renderDataTable({
  print(as.data.frame(cor(df[2:3],)))
})
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the output to show in the `flexdashboard` by making these small changes. If you are having trouble in the RStudio console, try also clicking the "Open in Browser" button. I have noticed odd behavior at times when the `DT` only has a couple rows and columns, but not sure if this is just related to my machine.

````
```{r}
library(DT)

output$t10 <- DT::renderDataTable({
  datatable(cor(df[2:3],))
})

dataTableOutput("t10")
```
````